# How to login with facebook on android app with NODE.js server?

Tags: android, node.js, facebook

i created an android app that talks to a web server written in NODEjs, i built login/sign up system and its working good. I want to add the connect with facebook thing, i succeed added it to my application,and after i hit log in with facebook i get the access token and everything, but what do i do next? how i connect it to my node server? i need to register new account? but what the password would be? I didnt find a lot of information of how exctly all this done. I also know of passport.js(The facebook strategy) in node, but i cant seem to understand how it working if i already have the access token from my android app.
I would be happy if someone could explain me exctly how its all working and what i should do next. thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the login functionality provided by the Facebook Android SDK directly?

Comment: Do you mean with apigraph token checker?

Comment: I mean using the Login Button in the Android SDK. Difficult to understand your particular use case, but that should handle what you need.